# Password Authentication Failure error when running Django's sqlall command

Tags: python, django, python-2.7

I am working allong with Django book. Now I'm on the fifth chapter(Models) and right now I'm dealing with some problems. For instance, when I'm trying to write in my shell: **python.py manage.py sqlall my_app_name** I am getting this message:

[image: Error message]

Where is my mistake?

P.S. My my_app.models.py:

```
from django.db import models

class Publisher(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    state_province = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    country = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    website = models.URLField()

class Author(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    email = models.EmailField()

class Book(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    authors = models.ManyToManyField(Author)
    publisher = models.ForeignKey(Publisher)
    publication_date = models.DateField()
```

My project settings.py databases configuration:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'mydb',
        'USER': 'admin',                      # Not used with sqlite3.
        'PASSWORD': '123',                  # Not used with sqlite3.
        'HOST': '',                      # Set to empty string for localhost. Not used with sqlite3.
        'PORT': '',                      # Set to empty string for default. Not used wit
    }
}
```

And finally - my project settings.py INSTALLED_APPS and MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    #'django.contrib.admin',
    #'django.contrib.auth',
    #'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    #'django.contrib.sessions',
    #'django.contrib.messages',
    #'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'books', # MY APP NAME
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    #'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    #'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    #'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    #'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    #'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    #'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
)
```

If you need any more information just say. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message is quite explicit that this is a problem with connecting to the database with that username and password. Have you set that account up in Postgres?

Comment: Nothing is written about connecting username and pass to database. Also i can't find anythinf spesific on the google fast. So maybe you can write about that in very short way? Thanks btw.

Comment: Well, you've somehow chosen "admin"/"123" in your database settings. Where did you get that from? Anyway, this is a question about Postgres, not Django: you should look at the Postgres docs to learn how to set up a username. If you don't want to do that, just use sqlite3 instead.